# Droping columns based on the length value Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a Pyspark dataframe in which I need to check `number` column and if `drop the row if the size of value present is not 4`

```
    +------+
    |number| 
    +------+
    |  1234|
    |  1345|
    |   223|
    +------+
```

Required output:

```
+------+
|number| 
+------+
|  1234|
|  1345|
+------+
```

I know how to calculate the size of the number which can be done by using length(df.number) but I am unable to implement the required condition.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter and have only the numbers that are of length 4

```
 from pyspark.sql import functions as F


    # InputDF
    # +------+
    # |number|
    # +------+
    # |  1234|
    # |  1345|
    # |   223|
    # +------+

    df.filter(F.length("number") == 4).show()

    # OutputDF
    # +------+
    # |number|
    # +------+
    # |  1234|
    # |  1345|
    # +------+
```